# Can I apply the sum to every row when I use aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions

How can I apply the sum to every row when I use aggregate(or any other better functions)? Thanks a lot for your help!XD

**The original data**

```
Categories  vaule
A1           5
A2           3
C            2
B1           6
A3           1
B2           5
```

**Target**

```
 Categories Groups  SUM of the Group
    A1            A     9
    A2            A     9
    C             C     2
    B1            B     11
    A3            A     9
    B2            B     11
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Groups = str_remove(Categories, "\\d+")) %>% mutate(SUMOFGROUP = sum(value))`

Comment: Please do not use images for data.  Provide the data in a form that can be copied and pasted into R.  You can use `dput(x)` to provide `x` in reproducible form.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DF` defined in the Note at the end this is a base solution:

```
Group <- gsub("\\d", "", DF$Category)
transform(DF, Value = NULL, Group = Group, Sum = ave(Value, Group, FUN = sum))
```

giving:

```
  Category Group Sum
1       A1     A   9
2       A2     A   9
3        C     C   2
4       B1     B  11
5       A3     A   9
6       B2     B  11
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- 
"Category Value
A1 5
A2 3
C 2
B1 6
A3 1
B2 5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Instead of `read.table(text = Lines, …)` I had to use `read.table(textConnection(Lines), …)`.

Comment: That should not be necessary.   Try again.

Comment: I surely won't _try again_, since, as you should know, it's a sign of insanity to repeat the same thing and expect a different outcome.

Comment: Upgrade R to the latest and try it on a fresh vanilla session.  There is something wrong since text= does work as an argument to `read.table`.

Comment: As you seem to suspect by suggesting "Upgrade R", the behavior may well vary with different versions of R, and there's nothing wrong with that. Since I can so easily make it work, I need not bother to "upgrade".

Comment: The text= argument has worked for a long time so you would have to have a very old version of R for that not to work.  I think you could first try it on a fresh session in case there is something wrong with your current session.  `R --vanilla` will start a vanilla session without the .Rprofile in case there is something in that that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`.  Create the 'Groups' by removing the one or more digits from 'Categories' (`str_remove` from `stringr`) and then `mutate` to get the `sum` of 'value' after grouping by 'Groups'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Groups = str_remove(Categories, "\\d+")) %>%
   mutate(SUMOFGROUP = sum(value)) %>% 
   select(-value)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Groups [3]
#  Categories Groups SUMOFGROUP
#  <chr>      <chr>       <int>
#1 A1         A               9
#2 A2         A               9
#3 C          C               2
#4 B1         B              11
#5 A3         A               9
#6 B2         B              11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Categories = c("A1", "A2", "C", "B1", "A3", "B2"
 ), value = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("Categories", 
 "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```